# What is lightweight lock in distributed shared memory systems?

Tags: distributed-transactions

I started reading Tanenbaum's Distributed Systems book a while ago. I read about two phase locking and timestamp reordering in transactions chapter. While having a deeper look from google I heard of lightweight transactions/lightweight transactional memory. But I couldn't find any good explanation and implementation. So what is lightweight memory? What are the benefits of lightweight locks? And how can I implement them?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sébastien why do you think so?

Comment: Because you are not actually asking a question about code.

Comment: There are a lot of questions that are not about code in stackoverflow and they're high-voted. On the other hand I'm asking about the implementation, any code is appriciated ;)

Comment: You won't get code if you don't show some prior effort, but good luck.

Comment: To be able to write code I need good understanding as you will justify. There are a lot of questions here asked to have good understanding on a subject.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/about This is not a discussion forum.